# Deactivate Adobe Acrobat Pro 9 on a Macintosh

Tags: macos, adobe-acrobat, deactivation

I'm trying to deactivate some installed software on a Macintosh OS X v10.5.8.

When I launch Adobe Acrobat Pro 9, it comes up fine, but in the Help menu, the "Enter Serial Number..." choice is grayed out.  Does this mean that the serial number was never entered or that it has already been entered.  If already entered, how do I deactivate this copy? I did the same thing on Adobe Photoshop CS4 with no problem. In Photoshop, there was a "Deactivate" menu choice in the help menu, but in Acrobat, there is no such menu.

How can I deactivate Adobe Acrobat Pro 9?

Comment: You don't activate/deactivate installations of Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: Does it require a serial number? If so, how do they enforce the license, what keeps you from installing it repeatedly?

Comment: @Ramhound That contradicts what Adobe states here: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/100/1008779.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with Acrobat X. I was trying to deactivate and uninstall so I could request a refund in my 30 day window.

There is no "Deactivate" option in the Help menu. I uninstalled using the uninstaller application in the Acrobat X folder (in /Applications).

I wasn't able to immediately request a refund thru the Adobe site but was provided with their links to "deactivate and uninstall". However, the next morning my refund request  was accepted.

I wonder if the Adobe licensing services take care of the deactivation for you when you use the uninstaller?